# Notify browser download has started immediately with DeferredResult

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring boot app with @RestController returning DeferredResult, holding "application/pdf" byte[] (from a service I don't control). I want to notify the browser immediately that the download has started, to do this I flush the output stream with response header information.

My code shown below, works with Tomcat (locally & WebLogic) but not Tomcat on Azure Web App. The former shows pdf download in-progress in Chrome's status bar, the latter gives nothing until DeferredResult completes.
Is there a more reliable way to notify the browser of a download than flushing the response header?
Could it be teh code is fine and its Azure preventing the flush being sent to the client? Any help gratefully received.

```
@RequestMapping(value= DOWNLOAD_BASE_LINK + "/{documentType}/{correlationId}/*", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> download(@PathVariable final PaymentDocumentService.DocumentType documentType,
                                                      @PathVariable final String correlationId,
                                                      final HttpServletResponse resp,
                                                      final HttpServletRequest req) {
        LOGGER.debug("Is asyncSupported: [{}] - must be true for document download functionality", req.isAsyncSupported());
        LOGGER.info("Searching for documentType [{}] with correlationId [{}]", documentType, correlationId);

        final ResponseEntity timeoutResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(documentServiceTimeout, timeoutResponseEntity);
        final String documentFileName = paymentDocumentService.getDocumentFileName(documentType);

        resp.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + documentFileName + "\"");
        resp.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);

        //Give the browser the header data so it can show the download as started
        final OutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not get or flush outputStream");
            deferredResult.setResult(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE));
            return deferredResult;
        }

        ListenableFuture<DocumentData> futureDocumentData = paymentDocumentService.getDocument(documentType, correlationId);
        futureDocumentData.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<DocumentData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentData documentData) {
                LOGGER.debug("Start onSuccess: documentData received");
                deferredResult.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(documentData.getBytes(), HttpStatus.OK));
                LOGGER.info("End onSuccess: returning deferredResult [{}] (File download time={}ms", deferredResult, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Start onFailure: documentData type[{}] correlationId[{}] failed", documentType, correlationId, ex);
                deferredResult.setResult(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE));
                LOGGER.error("End onFailure: returning deferredResult [{}]", deferredResult);
            }
        });
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question above "Could it be the code is fine and its Azure preventing the flush being sent to the client?" is partly correct. Though not Azure, its actually the IIS web server buffering the response before sending it.
Here is the configuration to not buffer (responseBufferLimit zero) which solved my problem:

```
<handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
</handlers>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/add